# Get and set binding converter in code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a binding set to the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` in my XAML this way:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TextProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

I want to change the converter from the code-behind dependind on which is currently used. How can I get and set the converter of the binding from code behind? Id' like somthing like:

```
if (converter = x)
    converter = y;
else
    converter = x;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to get the binding itself:

```
//For WPF:
// var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingBase(
//     MyTextBlock,
//     TextBlock.TextProperty);

//For SilverLight we have to use the expression:
var expr = MyTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
if (expr != null)
{
    // for Silverlight we have to use the ParentBinding of the expression
    var binding = expr.ParentBinding;
    binding.Converter = yourLogicHere;

    // in WPF there are 3 types of bindings
    /*
    else if (binding is MultiBinding)
    {
        ((MultiBinding)binding).Converter = yourMultiLogicHere;
    }
    else if (binding is PriorityBinding)
    {
        foreach (var childBinding in ((PriorityBinding)binding).Bindings)
        {
            ((Binding)childBinding).Converter = yourLogicHere;
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: `BindingOperations` does not have `GetBindingBase` method, it only shows `SetBinding`. It says `'System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations' does not contain a definition for 'GetBindingBase'`

Comment: Oh, Silverlight...I'll update. Silverlight is a Second Class Citizen and isn't as well supported as WPF. I'd avoid it.